# ListView onclicklistener image

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I have a listview with 2 images in each row and I want the images to change on a click but I get an error whenever I click the item.
I set up a toast to confirm that I am clicking on the right item and that works.  But in the end what I really want is for the image to change.
Any suggestions on how to get the to set it up the right way?

---

```
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at com.codalata.craigslistchecker.AutomationSettings$TheListAdapter2.onClick(AutomationSettings.java:217)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9158)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3704)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-08 15:19:43.371: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

```
public class TheListAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<Auto_Info> implements
        OnClickListener {
    public TheListAdapter2() {
        super(AutomationSettings.this, R.layout.automationitems, Info);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View Auto_View = convertView;
        ImageHolder holder = null;

        if (Auto_View == null) {
            Auto_View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.automationitems, parent, false);
            holder = new ImageHolder();
            holder.item_auto_title = (TextView) Auto_View
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_auto_title);

            holder.item_auto_image1 = (ImageView) Auto_View
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_auto_image1);

            holder.item_auto_image2 = (ImageView) Auto_View
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_auto_image2);

            holder.item_auto_image1.setTag(R.id.item_auto_image1, holder);
            holder.item_auto_image2.setTag(R.id.item_auto_image2, holder);
            Auto_View.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ImageHolder) Auto_View.getTag();
        }

        Auto_View.setOnClickListener(this);

        Auto_Info CurrentItem = Info.get(position);
        holder.CurrentItem = CurrentItem;

        Typeface TitleFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "providence.ttf");
        holder.item_auto_title.setTypeface(TitleFont);
        holder.item_auto_title.setText(CurrentItem.getAUTONAME());

        holder.item_auto_image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.item_auto_image2.setOnClickListener(this);

        return Auto_View;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageHolder holder = (ImageHolder) v.getTag();
        if (v.getTag() == v.getTag(R.id.item_auto_image1)) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(AutomationSettings.this, "blah",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            holder.item_auto_image1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bstoppedrunning);
            t.show();

        } else if (v.getTag() == v.getTag(R.id.item_auto_image2)) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(AutomationSettings.this, "blah2",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }
    }
static class ImageHolder {
    public Auto_Info CurrentItem;
    ImageView item_auto_image1;
    ImageView item_auto_image2;
    TextView item_auto_title;
}
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is line 217?

Comment: holder.item_auto_image1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bstoppedrunning);

Comment: Make sure your holder is not null after the call to v.getTag()

Comment: Is ImageHolder your custom class? I can't find documentation on that.

Comment: yes it is I'm checking the holder now

Comment: It does go null after the get.

Comment: Are you sure getTag returns you ImageHolder?

Comment: Well it's not because its null so I'm guessing that's where the problem is.

Comment: What I meant was are you sure that getTag's return type can be casted into ImageHolder.